# How to send two parameter from yaml to socket.io using artillery.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, load-testing

Related: [Testing Socket.io - Artillery.io Docs](https://artillery.io/docs/socketio-reference/)

I don't know how to send two parameters, in my case for  "data" and "massage" from yaml emit to "send-room-message"

Socket.io

```
socket.on('send-room-message', function (data, message) {
    socket.broadcast.to(data.room).emit('get-room-message', data, message);
});
```

socketio-chat-load-test.yaml

```
config:
    target: "http://localhost:3030"  
phases:
- duration: 5 
  arrivalRate: 100   
variables:
greeting: ["hello", "goedemorgen", "добрый день", "guten tag", "bonjour", "hola"]  
variables:
room:
  - 2
scenarios:
 - name: "A user that just talks"
weight: 75
engine: "socketio"
flow:
  - get:
      url: "/"     
  - emit:          
      channel: "add-user"
      data: {"id": "112312", "Name":'Hello'}
  - emit:
      channel: "join-room"
      data: "2"
  - emit :
      channel: "push-room-button"
      data: "2"
      response: 
        channel: "room-busy"
        data: "2"
  - emit:
      channel: "send-room-message"
      data: <<--TODO-->>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This currently isn't supported by artillery. I found a way to do it though.
What you have to do is:

1. Fork [artillery-core](https://github.com/shoreditch-ops/artillery-core)
2. Open the file `engine_socketio.js`
3. Replace all `socketio.emit(...)` messages with the following code:

   ```
   const splitData = ougoing.data.split('|');
   socketio.emit(outgoing.channel, ...splitData);
   ```
4. Commit and push changes to your branch
5. Clone [artillery](https://github.com/shoreditch-ops/artillery)
6. Open package.json and change the dependency `artillery-core` to:
   `"artillery-core": "git://github.com/YOUR-GITHUB-USERNAME/artillery-core.git#YOUR-BRANCH",`
7. Run the command `npm link` in the directory in which you cloned artillery so it uses the version with the updated artillery-core in the command line.

Now when you use artillery you can specify the multiple parameters as such in your socketio-chat-load-test.yaml:

```
- emit:
        channel: "Insert your channel here"
        data: "Insert first parameter here|Insert second parameter|Third parameter"
```

Comment: Thanks!

FYI new ver changed this and does not use the artillery-core. You can clone artillery repo and make these changes straight into engine_socketio.js. Note there are 2 places (one with callback, one without)